# Independent multipoint support in the same desktop session

Tags: x11, desktop, xinput

I'd like to be able to collaborate with others in the same desktop environment, but not necessarily share the same cursor, keyboard, or other xinput masters. This is because many powerful desktop applications do not have a fast/private/cheap enough RTC substitute, and we don't want to buy multiseat licenses anyway. However, I'm not asking for the ability for multiple cursors and keyboards to simultaneously interact with the same window.

I've tried pure `xinput`, but not all applications behave properly with multiple curators.

I don't know if "desktop" or "X11 server" are the right terminology is for the behavior I'm seeking to implement, so please correct me if this is incorrectly asked:

Is there a linux desktop and X11 server system / configuration that enables multiple mouse cursors, keyboards, and other input devices to share the same GUI experience, while each xinput master has its own window and element in focus?

Comment: Hey, I must admit I don't understand your requirements: you want multiple cursors, but you don't require multiple cursors? Maybe I'm confused about what you describe as "xinput master".

Comment: I want multiple xinput masters with the ability to interact with separate applications simultaneously. But I don't need them to be interacting with the same application at the same time.

Comment: So, separate (virtual) displays? how would they then share the same desktop environment? There's exactly one focus…

Comment: Same virtual display. Separate cursors on the same display.

Comment: so, multiple cursors. It's really hard for me to visualize what you want...